# No puedo escribir un archivo en Java

Tags: java

tengo un problema con java y es que estoy intentando hacer un ejercicio donde leea una serie de multas y la velocidad almacenadas en un archivo infractores.in, y calcule la cantidad a pagar en multados.out, pero hace horas estoy intentando que escriba el archivo multados.out pero no lo hace, revise muchisimas veces la ruta, y no se que puede ser

el formato de infractores.in es el siguiente:

```
AXD765 65
AFR234 120
DXS654 140
ASD342 230
```

el codigo de mi programa es el siguiente

```
    package EjercicioDeParciales;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

    public class Infractores {
    private final Map<String, Integer> infractores = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    public Infractores(){


    }
    public void leerInfractores(String entrada) throws IOException{
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(new File("C:\\Users\\Fabian\\Desktop\\infractores.in"));
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        String linea;
        while((linea= br.readLine())!=null){
            String [] pmultados = linea.split(" ");
            if(linea.length() == 2 ){
                String patentes = pmultados[0];
                int velocidad = Integer.parseInt(pmultados[1]);
                if(velocidad>80){
                    int multa = ((velocidad - 80)*50000);
                    infractores.put(patentes, infractores.getOrDefault(patentes, 0)+multa);

                }

            }


        }

   br.close();

    }
    public void escribirMultados(String salida) throws IOException{
        PrintWriter multados = new PrintWriter ("C:\\Users\\Fabian\\Desktop\\multados.out");
        BufferedWriter juan = new BufferedWriter(multados);
        for (Entry<String, Integer> cu : infractores.entrySet()){
            String key = cu.getKey();
            Integer val = cu.getValue();
            juan.write(key +" "+ val);
            juan.newLine();

        }
        juan.close();
        multados.close();

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Infractores infractores = new Infractores();
        infractores.leerInfractores("C:\\Users\\Fabian\\Desktop\\infractores.in");
        infractores.escribirMultados("C:\\Users\\Fabian\\Desktop\\multados.out");


    }
}
```

Comment: REVISA LA CONDICIONAL linea.length() == 2  , por que la pones?? ;)

Comment: @Dramaturgo

AAAAAAA, muchisimas gracias, ahora voy a poder seguir estudiando para mi parcial :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En realidad, la validación debería ser si el array obtenido de la línea (`pmultados`) contiene dos elementos, la placa y la velocidad, realiza el siguiente cambio:

```
        ...
        ...
        //if(linea.length() == 2 ){
        if(pmultados.length == 2 ){
            String patentes = pmultados[0];
            int velocidad = Integer.parseInt(pmultados[1]);
            if(velocidad>80){
                int multa = ((velocidad - 80)*50000);
                infractores.put(patentes, infractores.getOrDefault(patentes, 0)+multa);

            }

        }
        ... 
        ...
```